# Maven build has missing package linkages

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-flink

I am having problems using Maven. I have an Apache Flink project and wanted to run it on my server. Locally it runs fine but on the server it aborts with the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/examples/java/ml/util/LinearRegressionData
```

In my Java project I imported the class with

```
import org.apache.flink.examples.java.ml.util.LinearRegressionData;
```

And I used the correct class at the import:

[image]

After the build I had a look into the Jar file. The following classes were included:

[image]

The /util/ folder is completely missing. My dependency-section in the pom file looks like the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-streaming-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-table</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I have seen the package organization in the repository located at https://github.com/apache/flink/tree/release-0.9, I thought it would be possible to add the following lines to flink:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-examples</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

But these dependencies cannot be resolved. Since Maven does not throw an error when performing a clean install, I think this is a dependency issue. I thought Maven would include all used imports automatically. How can I make this runnable on my server?

Comment: How do you start it locally and how on the server?

Comment: @hzpz I start it on the server with " /lib/flink-0.9.0/bin/flink run /lib/flink-0.9.0/project/apache-linear-regression-1.0-SNAPSHOT-flink-fat-jar.jar hdfs://flink:9000/data/inputfile_apache.csv hdfs://flink:9000/data/result_apache.csv 1". Locally I press the play button in my IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include ML example as follows:

```xml
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java-examples</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

`flink-examples` is a parent `pom` module; not a `jar` module. How do you build your jar file? Using `maven-jar-plugin`? A regular `mvn package` or `mvn install` does not packages dependencies.

Using `maven-jar-plugin` requires to specify what you need to include using `<include>`. See here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

In your case it should be something like this:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>org.apache.flink.examples.java.ml.LinearRegression</Main-Class>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>

        <includes>
                <include>org/apache/flink/examples/java/ml/*.class</include>
                <include>org/apache/flink/examples/java/ml/util/*.class</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can also compare with https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-java-examples/pom.xml

You also need to "pull" and unpack your dependencies into your project such that they can be re-packages using `maven-dependency-plugin`

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
                        <artifactId>flink-java-examples</artifactId>
                        <version>0.9.0</version>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The dependency can be resolved in the pom file but the `/util/` folder is still not included in the jar file. Executing on the server still fails. The flink wiki recommended to run `mvn clean` and `mvn install`, so I did this and moved the created jar file to the server. How am I able to package dependecies otherwise?

Comment: Can you share your complete pom file? This helps to debug.

Comment: You use `maven-assembly-plugin` at one point and `maven-jar-plugin` at another. Which one do you expect to build the jar you are submitting? (for `maven-assembly-plugin` you should share `src/assembly/flink-fat-jar.xml`, too)

Comment: Well, this is the file I got when I imported the project via Maven so I don't have a clue why `maven-assembly-plugin` and `maven-jar-plugin` are both active. Do they hinder each other? I only touched the dependency-section in the project. Here is the `flink-fat-jar.xml`: http://paste.debian.net/286721/ I didn't touch that file as well.

Comment: You can use either `maven-assembly-plugin` or `maven-jar-plugin` to build a jar file. `maven-assembly-plugin` is more flexible an powerful, but also more "difficult" to use. I would recommend to use `maven-jar-plugin` (you could use both is build different jar files -- in your case, I would remove `maven-assambly-plugin`). I am going to update my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the enhancement of your answer. Unfortunately the `/util/` folder is still not included in the jar. I tried it with and without commenting out the `<plugin>...</plugin>` section of the `maven-assembly-plugin`. Also adding the `<includes>...</includes>` section to the `flink-fat-jar.xml` file did not work when the assembly-plugin is not commented out. The assembly plugin and the jar plugin are creating two different jars as I figured out but none of them are containing the `/util/` folder.

Comment: The `<includes>` should be part of `maven-jar-plugin` (and not `maven-assembly-plugin` or `flink-fat-jar.xml`). It makes sense that two jars are build if you enable both plugins though. Can you update/share your new pom file?

Comment: The updated pom file can be found here: http://paste.debian.net/286725/
The `<include>**/util/**</include>` after your given solution did not work. I found it in the manual to include any util folder but that did not work either.

Comment: I forgot, that you also need to use `maven-dependency-plugin`. I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked well. I had to replace `<version>${project.version}</version>` with `<version>0.9.0</version>`, otherwise I got a Maven error. But could you just describe me in short why I need the `maven-dependency-plugin` and why I didn't need it for my projects I created before? What exactly does this plugin?

Comment: YW. Glad it works now. --- Adding a dependency downloads the corresponding jar, puts it into your maven cache (`$HOME/.m2/repository/`) and extends the classpath such that the compiler and local runtime finds the jar. `maven-jar-plugin` can only package stuff, that is in your `target/classes` folder.  Thus, `maven-jar-plugin` cannot find it as the stuff is located in the wrong place. `maven-dependeny-plugin` takes the jar file you want to include, and unpacks it into the folder specified via `<outputDirectory>` (`target/classes` in our case). Thus `maven-jar-plugin` can include the stuff now.

Comment: Okay, having this background-knowledge in mind, this makes sense. Thanks for the answer and the great help!